# Sending multiple data through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my question is an annoying combination of multiple smaller questions on stackoverflow as far as i've been able to find, but i can't get it figured out.

I'm trying to send an audio file over ajax, that works fine, but i also want to include the location where it was uploaded/ recorded. This is what I have made up reading through multiple similar question:

(it does not work)

```
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
    function foundLocation(position) {
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        //alert("LAT : "+latitude +", LONG : "+longitude);
        return [longitude, latitude];
    }
}

function noLocation() {
    //alert('Could not find location');
}

function uploadAudio(mp3Data){
    var pos = getLocation();
    var longitude = pos[0];
    var latitude = pos[1];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var mp3Name = encodeURIComponent('audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.mp3');
        console.log("mp3name = " + mp3Name);
        fd.append('fname', mp3Name);
        fd.append('data', event.target.result);
        fd.append('longitude', longitude);
        fd.append('latitude', latitude);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            log.innerHTML += "\n" + data;
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(mp3Data);
}
```

The php script I have to handle the data is as follows:

```
<?php

if(!is_dir("recordings")){
    $res = mkdir("recordings",0777); 
}

// pull the raw binary data from the POST array
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
// decode it
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
// print out the raw data, 
//echo ($decodedData);
$filename = 'audio_recording_' . date( 'Y-m-d-H-i-s' ) .'.mp3';
// write the data out to the file
$fp = fopen('recordings/'.$filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the location with something like $latitude = $_POST['longditude'];

Right now I have no idea how to make JS return multiple data in the getLocation() function, nor how to make ajax send all this data properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use ways like `$('input[name=longitude]').val();` or directly in your function `getLocation(longitude, latitude)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are sending file in raw format via `AJAX`, so you can not send more data in message body. So you should send data in `GET (query string)`.

**Client Side:**

```
function uploadAudio(mp3Data){
    var pos = getLocation();
    var longitude = pos[0];
    var latitude = pos[1];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var mp3Name = encodeURIComponent('audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.mp3');
        console.log("mp3name = " + mp3Name);
        fd.append('fname', mp3Name);
        fd.append('data', event.target.result);

        var ajax_url = 'upload.php?longitude='+longitude+'&latitude='+latitude;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            log.innerHTML += "\n" + data;
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(mp3Data);
}
```

**Server Side:**

```
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
```

Comment: Yeah that works for sending it to the server! Only issue right now is that var longitude = pos[0];
    var latitude = pos[1]; doesn't work. UPDATE: made a work around by creating 1 functionf for getting longitude, and 1 for latitude. So i just request 1 type of data at a time since this way of returning multiple data didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

To get all the returned values (if many) you must iterate through the response data, otherwise you will get only one.

```
.done(function(data) { 
    var output = '';
    $.each(data,function(index, value) {
       output += value

    });
}
```